# How can I use capitalized property in a hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

In our product we use auto generated hibernate entities to be able to link a customizable Database scheme to our server software. The entity names and property names are taken from the data base. Especially, the property names can usually not be changed as they also are used in user code unrelated to the hibernate data layer (e.g. python scripts)

Some of these property names are capitalized, which seems to cause some problems. HQL statements using those property names fail with an Exception, e.g.:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property List_id
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
```

Some code snippet for the example Exception:

```
@Entity(name = "ListItem")
@Table(name = "LIST_ITEM")
public class ListItem
    extends HibernatePojoClass
{
    private String List_id = "";

    @Column(name = "`LIST_ID`", length = 8)
    public String getList_id() {
        return List_id;
    }

    public void setList_id(String List_id) {
        this.List_id = List_id;
    }
...
```

and the HQL statement:
`select li.id, li.List_id from ListItem li`

The exception occurs when hibernate tries to transform the hql statement to a sql statement.

Why does this happen?

It seems that when I use `li.list_id` in the hql statement, the property is resolved (while this leads to another error); can I prevent this implicit "capitalization change" somehow?

Comment: Use `name = "LIST_ID"`, without the ticks.

Comment: as it is the property name ("List_id") that cannot be found, I doubt this would change anything...

Comment: Hibernate probably has difficulties with the name provided in the `@Column` annotation and thus might have ignored the field when creating the metamodel. Just to be safe try to fix that. Besides that when using getters to define properties Hibernate will remove the `get` from the getter and make the first character lower case thus `getList_id` results in the property being named `list_id` (Btw, if you'd stick to the Java code conventions that wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: @Thomas update: Removing the backticks does not solve the problem. the second part of your comment is just my question: How can I change/influence this behavior?

Comment: @v.ladynev the hibernate version is 4.3.4

Comment: Well you probably can't without altering Hibernate itself. After all JPA requires you to adhere to the Java Beans specification which states exactly that behavior (and which is based on the Java coding conventions). You could try with "field access" though. For more information have a look at sections 2.2 and 2.3 of the [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1467984563_cfeae259c5af3942804fa1517d954ba0)

Comment: @Thomas Could you please make an answer from this comment? field access does the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA has 2 basic access modes: property access and field access.

Property access requires you to adhere to the Java Beans convention which means you need field name that starts with a lower case character and a corresponding getter/setter which has the same character in upper case, i.e. field `listId` would require a getter `getListId()`.

Thus you'd need to use field access in order to have Hibernate use the field name as it is. Another advantage of using field access on an entity's id would be that you'd not need to do any lazy loading in order to just get the id - which wouldn't be possible with property access in Hibernate.

For more information have a look at sections 2.2 and 2.3 of the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1467984563_cfeae259c5af3942804fa1517d954ba0).

A final word of advice though: as already stated multiple times in my comments you should try and stick with the Java code conventions. Some advantages of doing so:

- It'll be easier to communicate with others such as people here on SO (e.g. a name starting with a capital letter normally is assumed to be a class name).
- You'll have less problems with libraries in the Java eco system since most of them use the same conventions or are based on them (e.g. JavaBeans, JavaEL, etc.)
- It'll be easier to spot errors, e.g. when using a class rather than a field or variable etc.
- You'll be less dependent on IDE features like code coloring, error highlighting etc.

Answer (score 3):

if you use

```
@Column(name = "`LIST_ID`", length = 8)
public String getList_id() {
  return List_id;
}
```

you should refer that property as `list_id` in HQL, of course.

Hibernate can use a naming strategy to generate column names. `ImprovedNamingStrategy` from Hibernate 4 will convert column name to the lower case, even if you specify it. I am not sure about the quotes, but for this:

```
@Column(name = "LIST_ID", length = 8)
public String getList_id() {
  return List_id;
}
```

using `ImprovedNamingStrategy` you will have `list_id` column name.

You can try to use your own naming strategy to generate correct column names.